# improve performance of double loop in pandas

Tags: pandas, performance

I have a dataframe consisting of numeric and categorical fields:

```
import pandas as pd
df2=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4],'col2':[5,6,7,8], 'col3':['cat','cat','dog','bird']})
df2
```

And am calculating how similar each row is with the following code:

```
#calculate distance matrix comparing how similar two rows are
vals=[]
for i in range(len(df2)):
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if(j<=i): continue
        a=df2.iloc[i,:]
        b=df2.iloc[j,:]

        d0=(a[0]-b[0])**2
        d1=(a[1]-b[1])**2
        d2=np.where(a[2]==b[2],0,10)**2

        row_values=(i,j, (d0 + d1 +d2)**0.5)
        vals.append(row_values)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns =['Row1','Row2','Difference'])
new_df
```

this works fine for a small dataframe, but when I implement it similarly to a dataframe that has 10k rows and 10 columns being used, it takes a very loooong time to compute.

Are there any suggestions on how to improve the processing power of this code?

I start with:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   1   5   cat
1   2   6   cat
2   3   7   dog
3   4   8   bird
```

and end up with:

```
    Row1    Row2    Difference
0   0   1   1.414214
1   0   2   10.392305
2   0   3   10.862780
3   1   2   10.099505
4   1   3   10.392305
5   2   3   10.099505
```

I am calculating the distance between each row of data.

Comment: your input df has columns with length 4, but the out put of function is a df with length 6. what is the logic of comparison?

Comment: @SH-SF pairs of `i != j` for `i=1..4` and `j=1..4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a distance matrix problem, so we can use `distance_matrix` and `broadcasting`. But note that this only works when your data is not too large.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

# normal distance:
d01 = distance_matrix(df2[['col1','col2']].values, df2[['col1','col2']].values)**2

# category distance
d2 = x = df2['col3'].values[:,None] != df2['col3'].values

# the matrix
dist_mat = np.sqrt(d1 + x*100)

# we only care for the distance with row != col
np.triu(dist_mat)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  1.41421356, 10.39230485, 10.86278049],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        , 10.09950494, 10.39230485],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , 10.09950494],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: need to change dist_mat = np.sqrt(d01 + x*100), but works great, thanks